# Concise Xpath to simulate finding an element regardless of page structure? (selenium)

Tags: selenium, xpath

If you're visually looking at a webpage and there is something clickable and unique on the page, you'll just click it. Without thinking about the page structure.

I'm interested to see what the most concise xpath is that could be constructed to simulate this in a versatile manner.

For example, target the "I'm feeling Lucky" button on the Google homepage:

```
//*[contains(@*, 'Lucky')]
```

The above works. But would fail in the element contained Lucky as inner text, or if the wrong case was specified. As such, our xpath needs to cater for any sensitivity and also look for the given string matching inner-text as well.

How could the above xpath be expressed in the most concise yet encompassing structure?

Comment: //*[contains(., 'Lucky')]

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing thats very generic and executing such xpaths could be costly also at times.

```
"//*[contains(@*, 'Lucky')] | //*[contains(text(), 'Lucky')]"
```

Above is one xpath you can combine to get some results. You start specifying which nodes you don't to examine or ones which you want to examine

```
"//*[contains(@*, 'Lucky')] | //*[contains(text(), 'Lucky')][not(self::script|self::td)]"
```

And you can keep improving it

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a **versatile XPath** to accurately/reliability locate an element by text.

Why?

- Because the text evaluated by an XPath is not necessary rendered in the page.
- Because there's a hight chance to end-up with multiple matches since each ancestor also contains the expected text.
- But mainly because there's too many rules/specific cases to consider.

But if I had to create one, then I'd start with this one:

```xpath
"(html/body//*[not(self::script or self::style)][contains(concat(@value, normalize-space()), 'MyText')])[last()]"
```

Get all the descendants of the `<body>`

```
html/body//*
```

except `<script>` and `<style>`

```
[not(self::script or self::style)]
```

where the `value` attribute or normalize html contains 'MyText'

```
[contains(concat(@value, normalize-space()), 'MyText')]
```

then returns the last and deepest match

```
[last()]
```